# Iterating through list of interfaces

Tags: c#

I've got an interface with type T objects like so

```
public interface IService<T>
```

I've got a bunch of these interfaces with all different type T's. How can I add these interfaces into a List of some sort, iterate through the list and call a common method used by the interface. Any ideas? Is there an alternative approach?

If I add it to a list, I just can't see a way of casting the type T correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the method is common, then presumably it doesn't depend on the `T`, so you should be able to do:

```
interface IService {
    void TheMethod();
}
interface IService<T> : IService {
    // other stuff
}
```

then have a `List<IService>`, and just:

```
foreach(var svc in list) svc.TheMethod();
```